# How to send result of an yield on a promise as a stream in express 4?

Tags: json, node.js, express, promise, streaming

Is there any way I could send the result of yielding a promise as a steam?

The JSON payload in some cases will be huge, it would make sense sending it as a stream.

```
function aPromise() {
    // result of a postgres query. Using `pg`
    return Promise.resolve([
           {key1: val1, key2: val2 }
   ]);
  });
}

//express 4 router
let wrap = require('co-express');

router.get('/', wrap(function* (req, res, next) {
    let payload;

    try {
        payload = yield aPromise();
    } catch (e) {
        return next(e);
    }

    res.json(payload);
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're fetching and loading into memory the whole object of your response, it's going to be hard to then reasonably turn it into streaming again. Anyway, [streaming JSON implementation](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSONStream) is needed here.

[Streaming postgress query](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-query-stream) should be a good source for JSONStream.

Here's two examples of how you can make it work, where I made some assumptions:

1. You are capable of creating a stream of tuples like this: `[key, data]` for each key you want to put in the resulting json being sent out. This assumes your data is a lot of keys.

   res.set('content-type', 'application/json');
   keystream.pipe(JSONStream.stringifyObject()).pipe(res)
2. You are capable of creating a stream of objects that you want to return as items in an array for the final json response.

   res.set('content-type', 'application/json');
   itemsstream.pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res)

Comment: The method `aPromise` uses `pg` to fetch a huge data set from postgres in one shot.  Is there any other detail that you need?

Comment: You need to know your data structure and decide what to do with it. No matter what, pulling huge datasets into memory in node is not a good idea. That's why you should stream. Updated my answer with streaming

Comment: In that case, using generators goes out for a toss, right?

Comment: streams are the old generators and `req` and `res` objects support them by default (they are streams themselves) and if you want to use generators here you'd have to implement streams API to translate to a generator and then from generators back. Sounds fun but pointless ;)

Comment: umm, some code to show how to actually do the above without generators and promises would be really helpful.

Comment: I don't know your data. you get a stream from pg, pipe it to json stringify and pipe that to res. I can add an example tomorrow